# How to webscrape flights using Python

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping

I am webscraping a website for flight tickets. My problem is: I am using Chrome developer to identify the class of the HTML object I want to scrape. However, my code does not find it. It looks like I am not downloading the HTML code I can see in the Chrome Developer Extension. (inspect item...)

```
import requests 
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
 
url = 'http://www.momondo.de/flightsearch/?Search=true&TripType=2&SegNo=2&SO0=BOS&SD0=LON&SDP0=07-09-2016&SO1=LON&SD1=BOS&SDP1=12-09-2016&AD=1&TK=ECO&DO=false&NA=false'
req = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content)
x = soup.findAll("span" ,{"class":"value"} )
```

Comment: If I found out someone was scraping my website for their own profit, I'd block their access asap. Keep in mind that websites sometimes provide API's that you can use. Also, what will happen when they change their site layout/structure?

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request

source = urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.momon...e&NA=false').read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(source,'html5lib')
for item in soup.find_all("span", class_="value"):
    print(item.text)
```

With this you can scrape all the spans of the webpage with the class "value". If you want to see the whole html element and its attributes instead of just the content, remove `.text` from `print(item.text)`.

You will probably need to install html5lib with pip, if you are having trouble doing this try running CMD as admin (assuming you are using windows).

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this:

```
for values_in_x in x:

    print(values_in_x.text)
```